# Does including "Pattern.LITERAL" flag as part of the Pattern.compile(String regex, int flags) method in Java mitigate String regex injection?

Tags: java, regex, security

In the below code base, I am providing Pattern.LITERAL as one of the flags to Pattern.compile(String regex, int flags) method and wanted advise whether this flag can mitigate regular expression injection(https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS) in Java or not? Below is an example pattern i have provided as an example. The string this regex is checked against is an user provided input.

private final int flags = Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.LITERAL;

```
   Pattern patternCheck = Pattern.compile("check\\s+test\\s+([\\w\\s-]+)cd(\\s+" + variable1 +
    "|\\s+abc\\s+" + variable2 + ")\\s+to\\s+(abc|xyz)\\s+test\\s+ab\\s+xyz",flags);
```

Comment: With `Pattern.LITERAL`, you "ruin" the regex since it is now treated as plain text, not a regex pattern.

Comment: If you want to prevent user from passing any regex syntax you can wrap his data in `Pattern.quote` before adding it to your regex. Otherwise Pattern.LITERAL would make *entire* regex be treated as plain text making `\\s` to actually match only sequence of ``\`` and `s`.

Comment: @Pshemo , i tried using Pattern.quote , but it breaks the regex check by adding \Q and \E at beginning and end of the regex string. Any idea, how this can be solved?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, then can you please advise on how to solve the security issue associated with it, if Pattern.LITERAL is not an option?

Comment: 1) Do not write regex patterns that can lead to catastrophic backtracking, 2) Do not pay attention to Sonarqube warnings after that.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "*but it breaks the regex check by adding \Q and \E at beginning and end of the regex string*"? I am not sure how you would end up with \Q \E at beginning and end of the regex since what I suggest was something more like `"regexA"+Pattern.quote(userData)+"regexB"` so it should generate something more like `regexA\Qxyz\EregexB`. Also `Pattern.quote` will escape \Q and \E inside quoted text, so user will not be able to use then like `\EbadRegex\Q` which would otherwise result in \Q\EbadRegex\Q\E making \Q\E reduntant.

Comment: Thanks @Pshemo, i will check that, if user input can be wrapped before adding as part of regex.

Comment: Yeah @WiktorStribiżew, i missed the part where you are asking to embed only user data under quote method, i was thinking, it is for the complete regex, ( my bad) , i will try this out and will get back once it is solved soon. Thanks.

Comment: It was Pshemo's advice. And you want `Pattern patternCheck = Pattern.compile("check\\s+test\\s+([\\w\\s-]+)cd(\\s+" + Pattern.quote(variable1) +
    "|\\s+abc\\s+" + Pattern.quote(variable2) + ")\\s+to\\s+(abc|xyz)\\s+test\\s+ab\\s+xyz", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [`Pattern.LITERAL` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#LITERAL):

> When this flag is specified then the input string that specifies the pattern is treated as a sequence of literal characters. Metacharacters or escape sequences in the input sequence will be given no special meaning.

So, this flag makes any pattern a plain text. `\s` will match `\s` text, not any whitespace.

What you need to make sure of is:

- Try to write patterns where each subsequent part cannot match the same text as the preceding part to avoid excessive backtracking
- Escape the user-written literal parts of the pattern using `Pattern.quote`.

In your case, you can use

```java
Pattern patternCheck = Pattern.compile("check\\s+test\\s+([\\w\\s-]+)cd(\\s+" + Pattern.quote(variable1) + "|\\s+abc\\s+" + Pattern.quote(variable2) + ")\\s+to\\s+(abc|xyz)\\s+test\\s+ab\\s+xyz", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ Wiktor Stribiżew, this worked.